# Getting resource path files from the context of a scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-2.11

I would like to make a macro that validates at compile time the existence of resources in other projects.  Is it possible to get this information from the context?

```
  def example_impl(c: Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    //instead of  
    // val r = this.getClass().getResource("/file.txt")

    val r = c.somthing.getResource("/file.txt")
    //...
  }
```

It may not be possible.  But if it is, I'd like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider what is a "resource". A resource is a file that can be found starting at the directories in the classpath. Note that, for this purpose, a jar file is a directory, as it stores a zip filesystem. A classpath is an environment information available *when running Java*.

And there's the fundamental problem: the Scala compiler does not know *where* these resources are! It receives source *files* to compile, maybe a *destination* directory, and it has its own classpaths, but they are related to running scalac, not to the code scalac is compiling.

It's not the compiler which "generates" the resources -- neither scalac, nor javac. It's other tools, such as `jar` (the command line tool), and usually called by still other tools, like the build systems (ant, maven, sbt).

Therefore, there's no information on where these resources can be found -- they are usually in directories separate from the source code anyway. You could use normal Scala file i/o support to traverse directories and such, but there's no "resource source" information available at compile time.

Comment: That's too bad, but I sort of suspected that was the case.

Comment: I need to review this again.  I believe it could be done through Context.classpath

Answer (score 1):

I did eventually get this working with `Context.classpath`.

https://github.com/marklemay/sacala-validation-macros/blob/master/macroHost2/src/main/scala/macroHost/Macros.scala

However I have only tested it within the scala IDE (eclipse).  It would have to be tested it in sbt, intelij, maven and scalac before I was confident with it.